# How to convert '2017-11' to 'November 2017' in SQL

Tags: sql, type-conversion

I want to convert or turn a string to date, but display like 'November 2017'

My field is: `[Fiscal_post_year_month] nvarchar(max)`

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: What's the database?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to put a guess that you are using MSSQL, this should do what you want.

```
DECLARE @THEDATE NVARCHAR(MAX)

--need to have some kind of 'DAY' but we won't use it
SET @THEDATE = '2017-11' + '-01'

--we turn the number back into a VARCHAR and then concatenate them together as per your request
SELECT DATENAME (MONTH, @THEDATE) + ' ' + CAST(DATEPART (YEAR ,@THEDATE) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
```

results:

[image]

Comment: Just use `datename()` for the year as well.  No `cast()` is necessary.